# SonarQube: Unable to read plugin manitest - SonarQube Server won't start - How do I fix this?

Tags: windows, service, sonarqube

Running SonarQube 5.6 LTS as a service on Windows Server 2012 R2. It has been running fine in our initial deployment with Subversion-based projects. I installed the GitHub support via the Adminstration-->Updates menu. It wanted a restart so I said OK. I'm getting this in the sonar log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read plugin manifest from jar : D:\Sonar\sonarqube\extensions\plugins\sonar-github-plugin-1.3.jar
```

How do I correct it? If the jar file is corrupt is there a better source? If so where do I correct it in configuration or properties files given that I can't start the service to use the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted the GitHub JARs from \sonarqube\extensions\plugins and was able to start the service. One of the JARs was 0 bytes so I suspect something happened while downloading the new JARs. Will try to re-install GitHub support now that I've figured out how to get rid of the entries should there be a problem.

Comment: Exact. For my information has the JAR file been downloaded through update center or manually copied in the directory ?

Comment: Update center. I guess something burped. I'll try again later.

Comment: Ok thanks. Ticket has been created to verify integrity of downloaded files : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8189

Answer (score 0):

The error is  D:\Sonar\sonarqube\extensions\plugins\sonar-github-plugin-1.3.jar can't be download from maven, you can download sonar-github-plugin-1.3.jar from https://repo-maven-apache-org.azurefd.net/maven2/org/sonarsource/javascript/sonar-javascript-plugin/6.2.1.12157/ and put the jar to this line.

I had solved this problem by this method, good luck to you ~
by the way, mysql sq build with docker, so I use docker cp sonar-javascript-plugin-6.2.1.12157.jar 8576d3758142:/opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins and restart docker to solve.